# Cloudflare API PHP error

Tags: php, cloudflare

I am trying to add a record to Cloudflare via their API using PHP. For some reason, when I use the same code, the result sometimes gives me success, but at other times, it gives an error saying:

```
Could not route to /zones/dns_records, perhaps your object identifier is invalid?
```

and it gives the HTTP response code of `400` and `429`. After searching those codes, I learned that the code `429` was something about too many requests. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: 400 is not too many requests, it's client error meaning your request was not made according to the API specifications. 429 is "too many requests" meaning you've reached your request quota so you'll need to wait.

Comment: @apokryfos yes, I know that 400 is client error, but the thing is that there is actually NO error at all. The request that I make **sometimes** gets a success and doesn't return 400 and 429, but other times it does.

Comment: Don't group 400 and 429 together. 429 is an error you should expect to get occasionally when you exceed the requests you're allowed to make. Inspect only cases where you get a 400 error and check if the error is reproducible with the exact same request.

Comment: @apokryfos Every time when I get 429, it always comes back with both 429 and 400. When the call was successful, it obviously returns 200. I never have gotten ONLY 400.

Comment: How can a single response have 2 status codes? Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are querying the wrong endpoint, the `dns_records` endpoint is in the format of `/zones/:zone_identifier/dns_records`

You will need to substitute `:zone_identifier` with the ID of a given zone, you can get this using the `/zones` endpoint.

So if you want to add a DNS record using cURL:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/dns_records" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"type":"A","name":"example.com","content":"127.0.0.1","ttl":120,"proxied":false}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error today:

```
Could not route to /client/v4/zones/dns_records, perhaps your object identifier is invalid?
```

In my case it was because a **new domain was just added to CloudFlare** minutes ago and the zone / records were **not yet properly confirmed**.

You can debug this by trying to access zones for a domain that is already with cloudflare for a while.